# Python Permutations unexpected behavior?

Tags: python, permutation

Given the sample below:

```
from itertools import permutations
p=permutations("abc", 2)

def func():
  for i in p:
      print("values=", i)
        

print("First use case:") 
func()

print("Second use case:") 
func()

print("The End!")
```

**Output:**

```
First use case:
values= ('a', 'b')
values= ('a', 'c')
values= ('b', 'a')
values= ('b', 'c')
values= ('c', 'a')
values= ('c', 'b')
Second use case:
The End!
```

The question is about the second *function* CALL, why doesn't print the values?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is and iterator which means once you finish iterating through it there are no more elements in it. You will have to regenerate the iterator.

Like:

```
def func():
  p=permutations("abc", 2)
  for i in p:
      print("values=", i)
```

If you have situation where the iterator is generated randomly and you want to use the same random elements then you will have to move them to something like a list.

Example:

```
from numpy.random import permutation
import numpy as np
p =  list(iter(np.random.randint(0,10,10)))

def func():
  for i in p:
      print("values=", i)
```